# PHP chat form redirects using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, mysqli

I am having a simple chat with several files:

- chat.php - the form with username and message fields, and submit button with action: chat_send.php.
- chat_send.php - inserts into the database the username and message.
- chat_receive.php - the file that reads the database

The problem is that I cannot make it work without reloading. I know I should use Ajax, but the code I have put in simply does not work. It is supposed to read the messages from the database and without refreshing the page show the messages in the chat box. Where is my problem?

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#send').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();     
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    var data = $(this).serialize();  
    $.post(url, data)
      .done( function(response) {
        $('#response').html(response);
      })
      .fail( function() {
        alert("The AJAX request failed!");
      });
  });
});
```

**CHAT.PHP**

```
<form action="chat_send.php" method="post" class="send" id="form1" >
  <p>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  </p>
  <div style="width: 480px; height: 400px; border-right: darkslategray thin solid; border-top: darkslategray thin solid; font-size: 10pt; border-left: darkslategray thin solid; border-bottom: darkslategray thin solid; font-family: verdana, arial; overflow:scroll; text-align: left;" id="DIV_CHAT">
  </div>
    <p>
    <label for="emailAddress"></label>
    <textarea id="msg" rows="5" cols="66" name="msg" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea></p>
    </p>
  <input class="submit" type="submit" id="button1" name="submit" value="Send" onfocus="this.blur()"  />
</form>
```

**CHAT_SEND.PHP**

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) {}else
  {
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysqli,$_POST['name']);
    $msg = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['msg']);
    $dt = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
      $sql = "INSERT INTO messages (username, chatdate, msg) VALUES ('$name', '$dt', '$msg')";
      mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
}
    $mysqli->close();
```

**CHAT_RECEIVE.PHP**

```
  $sql = "SELECT *, date_format(chatdate,'%d-%m-%Y %r') as cdt from messages order by ID desc limit 200";
  $result = $mysqli->query(  "SELECT * FROM (" . $sql . ") as ch order by id");
  $msg="<table border='0' style='font-size: 10pt; color: blue; font-family: verdana, arial;'>";
     while ($line = $result->fetch_array())
     {
           $msg = $msg . "<tr><td>" . $line["cdt"] . "&nbsp;</td>" .
                "<td>" . $line["username"] . ":&nbsp;</td>" .
                "<td>" . $line["msg"] . "</td></tr>";
     }
     $msg=$msg . "</table>";
     echo $msg;
```

I have tried all stackoverflow Ajax solutions but no luck with that.

Comment: Create a JavaScript function which makes an AJAX request to CHAT_RECEIVE.php, then call this function periodically - say every 10 seconds. You could look into piggybacking and indefinite connections as alternate methods of checking for new messages.

Answer (score 0):

Most obvious thing that I can see is that your jQuery selector for the form `$('#send')` doesn't match because the ID of the form is `form1`, the class is `send`, so either change to `$('.send')` or `$('#form1')`.

Comment: Actually, with changing this -> my submit button does not work :(

Comment: Check in the console to see if the AJAX request went through... `e.preventDefault()` will stop the form from actually submitting, but that's how it should work.